# Empty properties vs New Class?

Tags: c#, json, performance, oop, serialization

When deserializing similar data from json to a class object. Is it more efficient to:

A) Have a class that may have null properties?

B) Have a separate class with only the properties you would expect to see?

For example: in the case where I want to have data like this:

```
public class Author
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string prev { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say in this case, only `id` and `type` ever gets populated for `Author` and we never expect the others.

Would it be more efficient/better to then do the following?

```
public class Author
{
    public AuthorData data { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorData
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

This is obviously a case where `Data` may be used in different ways in different places, and therefore at different times have other properties null.

Our code base would obviously have much less objects by recycling `Data`, but how will doing this affect the application execution? 
Is it "wrong" to used generally typed classes like this for deserialization?

Comment: It all depends on your definition of "efficient". The only person that can tell that, is you, by trying both versions and testing.

Comment: Well efficiency is the key factor- but I would also know what is the "standard" for dealing with situations such as this. I will test both and decide if it really comes down to only being a matter of efficiency and not standards.

Comment: There is no standard, every app is different and requires different solutions. In reality you will probably always find that there is no noticeable difference. Read this: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Usually the time budget for dealing with serialization issues is so low that it doesn't matter as long as it works.  If you are working in the low latency space then you are using binary fixed structs for almost everything and in those cases you do usually serialize everything even if null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as said in the comments there's a minimal speed and size difference in leaving null properties out, if you have the ability to neglect those minor advantages, I'd include always include the properties without value.

Why? It means the receiving party does not have to first check whether each property exists before parsing your JSON into the corresponding class on the receiving end.

Also, if I serialize your JSON in a C# application, the property would be there again anyways with a default value, and I'd still have to build in how to handle null values for the property, so you might as well make it easier for the receiver by at least knowing the property will always be there.